# How to convert String into Float?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm required to covert the variable:

```
pi_string = "3.1415926"
```

into a float. Here's what I'm dealing with:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: just reverse the assignment to `pi=float(pi)`.Please go through docs or search before you post a question.

Comment: Why yo think pi_string is astring?

Comment: What was unclear about *"can't assign to function call"*?

Comment: Please read [ask] before any further posts.

Comment: Make sure that the value in the string itself is a valid floating point number first[,](https://semicolon.dev/stackoverflow/question/8/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-float-in-python) for example `"1.4abf"` is not a proper float.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your line should be `pi_float = float(pi_string)`

`float(pi_string)` is a float value, you can not assign to it, because it is not a variable.

Answer (score 5):

The method `float()` will do this for you if `pi_string = "3.1415926"`.

```
>>>pi_float = float(pi_string)
>>>type(pi_float)
<class 'float'>
```